# Flutter Gpay previously working in production is not working now

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, production, google-pay

In the version that is on Playstore Gpay works fine. I want to update the app on the Play Store with new changes, however, Gpay has stopped working at the moment.
It shows the following error: [image]

I have set the environment to PRODUCTION in Google Pay config. I have used live Stripe Keys.

My dependencies inside Gradle are:

[image]

I have kept this inside the manifest File.

[image]

Our business profile is also approved.

[image]